# declare field without initial value in php?

Tags: php, oop

I don't want to give an initial value.  I want to set these later using the set method

```
class Duck {
    var int id;
    var set = Array();
}
```

Any idea how to declare without getting error?

Comment: PHP uses loose typing. You can only type hint in function or exception parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is marked PHP but it doesn't look like any PHP I know. This is correct PHP:

```
class Duck {
  private $id;
  private $set = array();
}
```

You don't need to specify an initial value for `$set` as in this example but that just means it gets the standard default value of 0, `false`, `array()`, etc depending on how it's used so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

You're typically better off being explicit.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Duck { var $int, $set = array(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Much more PHP is:

```
 class Duck {
      public $id;
 }

 $d = new Duck;
 $d->id = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

A method could be Typ checking;

```
private $props = array();
static $types = array ("id" => "is_integer","name" => "is_string");

public function __set($name,$value) 
{
   if(array_key_exists($name, self::$types)) 
   {
      if(call_user_func(self::$types[$name],$value)) 
      {
        $this->props[$name] = $value;
      }
      else 
      {
        print "Type assignment error\n";
        debug_print_backtrace();
      }
   }
}
```